# Cannot add elasticbeanstalk environment created with EB cli to a VPC: This environment is not part of a VPC

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc, vpc

Firstly, the use case: I have a large Spring Boot monolith which is accompanied by some smaller go services which are used to perform some tasks. Currently they are hosted privately and simply on the same server and can therefor communicate internally using localhost. I am looking into deploying this to AWS as ElasticBeanstalks and is currently using free tier for evaluating this. I want the Spring Boot application to be publicly visible and the go services to be available for the Spring Boot application but not to the public. My impression is that I want to deploy them as separate ElasticBeanstalk environments but assign them to the same VPC. If that is the wrong assumption please let me know of the correct one!

If that is however what we want, then this is my current initial issue. I have VPC set up (with default values) and in my local repository I use `eb init`, `eb create` etc to deploy the application. When it is deployed and up an running and I go into `Configuration` in the AWS console of the EB then network part simply says `This environment is not part of a VPC.`. I've tested to select classic, application and network as the loadbalancer but with the same result. Do I need to do something during `eb create` instead?

I've tried `eb create --vpc` but honestly don't know what to fill in for all the prompts:

```
Enter the VPC ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Do you want to associate a public IP address? (Y/n): Y
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon EC2 subnets: ?
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon ELB subnets: ?
Do you want the load balancer to be public? (Select no for internal) (Y/n): ?
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon VPC security groups:
```

What should I be looking for to enter here? The VPC ID i assume is the VPC id of the VPC I have created but I am having difficulties understanding the rest of them. If I try to simply run `eb create --vpc.id <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>` then I instead get `ERROR: ServiceError - Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'internal' (Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc', OptionName: 'ELBScheme'): Internal load balancers are valid only in a VPC; however, your environment is currently not running in a VPC.`

Grateful for help!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need two separate VPCs for your public facing applications. In the same vpc, you can create a load balancer as `Internal` and create another load balancer as `Internet facing`.

here is some information about the fields.

- Enter the VPC ID: vpc-abc123
- Do you want to associate a public IP address? (Y/n): 
  if internet facing, Yes. 
  this will assign a public ip address to the load balancer
- Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon EC2 subnets: ?
  You can enter the list of private subnets, private subnets cannot be accessed from the internet directly, thats why you create a public facing load balancer (for the internet facing application) receive the web traffic and forward to the instances.
- Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon ELB subnets: ?
  For Internet facing application, you need to choose public subnets.
  For internal application, you need to choose private subnets

Do you want the load balancer to be public? (Select no for internal) (Y/n): ?

- For Internet facing application, Yes
- For internal application, No

Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon VPC security groups: The security should be created for the VPC. in other words, if you inspect the security group, you should see your vpc id.

Comment: Thanks! I don't want to add multiple VPC's but to add multiple environments to one VPC just like your saying. However, due to not fully understanding subnets and such. How would one chose the EC2 and ELB subnets? Would it be possible for you to provide an example? In my case I have 2 ELB environments which I want in the same VPC. One should be public facing and one shouldn't be but I want them in the same VPC to be able to communicate internalle. If i use `eb create --vpc` for both of them, what arguments would work?

Comment: Lets say VPCId = vpc-1234 and I have a security group for the VPC which has id: sec-1234.  Then for the public facing one: ```Enter the VPC ID: vpc-1234
Do you want to associate a public IP address? (Y/n): Y
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon EC2 subnets: ?
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon ELB subnets: ?
Do you want the load balancer to be public? (Select no for internal) (Y/n): Y
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon VPC security groups: sec-1234```

Comment: And the internal one ```Enter the VPC ID: vpc-1234
Do you want to associate a public IP address? (Y/n): n
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon EC2 subnets: ?
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon ELB subnets: ?
Do you want the load balancer to be public? (Select no for internal) (Y/n): n
Enter a comma-separated list of Amazon VPC security groups: sec-1234```

Can I just select the subnet range which is the same for both? And how do I know which subnets are private and public? Do i need to create them first? Apparent confusion here :)

Comment: I'm sorry. if a subnet don't have routes to internet, it's a private  subnets. Private subnets don't have access to Internet and not reachable from internet.

Comment: Yes you need to create the subnets first. I will see if I can find a step by step tutorial for you.

Comment: Alright, starting to make a bit more sense to me, thanks! So I need to provide public subnets for the ELB and also select "Yes" on having the load balancer public in order for it to be properly public? Do i specify the name of the subnets or the ip ranges?

Comment: Yes you are right. No ip ranges or name needed. But just thought of something. I think your private subnets should be able to access internet in order to setup elasticbeanstalk. You need a nat gateway . I know it's confusing . But hard to explain all the concepts in one question. A `nat gateway` is a gateway that runs on public subnets to facilitate internet access for private subnets. ;)

Comment: Looking at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udY8x_g0dTk cleared things up I think. Will give that a go! And yeah, he's using a NAT gateway.